# How to find panoID in a new Google maps?

Tags: view, panorama-control, panoramas

PanoID use to be easy to find in the URL in classic maps for a photosphere/Google Business View shot. Unfortunately, they are not available anymore. 
Does anyone know how to find that stupid panoid?

Answer (score 0):

The pano ID is no longer a 22 character string. The ID now consists of multiple strings separated by a slash. For example:

https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Acropolis+of+Athens/@37.9715323,23.7257492,3a,75y,5.43h,104.71t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-wBhdou4p2Mk%2FVoC0geL2n8I%2FAAAAAAAAZ80%2FeRVCXmFDXBg!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2F-wBhdou4p2Mk%2FVoC0geL2n8I%2FAAAAAAAAZ80%2FeRVCXmFDXBg%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i9068!8i4534!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x0:0x5c97c042f5eb0df6!2sAcropolis+of+Athens!3m1!1s0x0:0x5c97c042f5eb0df6!6m1!1e1

The pano ID for the above is between the !1s and !2e:

`-wBhdou4p2Mk%2FVoC0geL2n8I%2FAAAAAAAAZ80%2FeRVCXmFDXBg`

And url decoded is:

`-wBhdou4p2Mk/VoC0geL2n8I/AAAAAAAAZ80/eRVCXmFDXBg`

There is currently a known bug which is documented here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7452#c51. This bug is preventing new panos from being embedded. Google states they are currently working on the issue and have pushed out a temporary method to enable using the new render method. Apparently this isn't ready for prime time yet which is why it is only available through an undocumented option:

```js
google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';
```

**Note:** It in order for this to work for us we had to prepend F: to the front of the pano ID (as per comment 80 https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7452#c80).